# Syntax check of bash build in commands arguments

Tags: bash

I have a list of logs from bash command line and I need to validate their syntax.

From my investigation I know that `bash -n` option or tools like https://www.shellcheck.net/ are not sufficient  because they do not recognize if executable for command exist or not.

Commands like `command`, `hash` or `type`, `which` could validate if command exist, but what I missed is how to check if their arguments are valid. (eg. I need to know that `ls -l` is valid and `ls -nonexistingargs` is not valid).

Any ideas how to do this? (solution for only build in bash commands is enough).

Comment: You can run them one by one in an isolated environment and check exit status of each and in the addition log the entire output and browse it manually if it's not too big.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk thanks, but it must be fully automated syntax check, and for example ssh command with some valid arguments  may not return 0 when I run it, even if it is syntactic right

Comment: There is no general solution for this. Arguments are interpreted by the command, so you would essentially need to run (a subset of) `ls` to determine if `ls` would accept whatever arguments you passed.